# Blackberry 'ControlledAccess' exception for persistent storage when launching from alternate entry point

Tags: exception, blackberry, code-signing, persistent-storage, alternate

Background:
I have an application with an alternate entry point. It listenes for SMS and Email sent events. The application get launched normally from the 'Download' folder (by user) and also when an SMS or Email is sent (upon user confirmation). When the application is launching, I have to pull out some flags from persistent storage to make some decisions. The application is signed properly by RIM provided keys. It is also signed by a key using signing authority tool to make the persistent storage isolated for this application.

Problem:
When launching normally from the menu, the data from persistent storage can be pulled out without any problem. But when launching from the alternate entry point (from SMS and Email sent event), the persistent storage is not accessible and the ControlledAccess exception is shown. Note that, I tried allowing all kinds of permissions for the applicaiton.

Possible Reason:
Although the application .cod file is properly signed by the key, it is being considered not signed when launching from alternate entry point. Thus the access to the persistent storage is not allowed.

I am looking for a solution or any suggestion that might help me troubleshoot the problem. Otherwise, I will have to drop off the feature of isolated persistent storage which I really don't want to.

Comment: For the SMS Email sent events are you implementing listeners registered with the OS? If that is the case your permission problem may be that what you have is not really an "alternate entry point". The listener may be executing your code as in the Messages app process.

Comment: Yes those listeners are registered using RIM API classes. Actually I found the reason of the problem. When an SMS or Email is sent the application is invoked within the context of that SMS or Email app which obviously are external apps. The solution is to use Global Event listener. I could post the link of BB forum here but not sure if that is allowed.

Comment: Good work, that is what I expected. You should post your solution and select it as the answer. You worked it out you should take credit, and it will close of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/ControlledAccess-exception-for-persistent-storage-when-launching/m-p/1542609#M189953